# ejecutar comados en multiples archivos

Tags: bash

Intento buscar archivos dentro de una carpeta y lo realice con las siguientes lineas:
`for r1 in *fastqc; do  echo $r1; find $r1 -type f -name "fastqc_data.txt"; done` e intento imprimir las líneas 4, 7, 9 y 10 de cada uno de los archivos y se que puedo usar la siguiente línea: `sed -n '4p;7p;9p;10p'`  per, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que la instrucción se ejecuté en cada uno de los archivos que buscó con find? y me los imprima en un solo archivo de texto

Comment: que has intentado o investigado para que: ***se ejecuté en cada uno de los archivos que buscó? y me los imprima en un soloarchivo de texto***

Comment: ¿en cada `r1` o en cada resultado del find?

Comment: en cada resultado de find